# Excel VB how to search text for value and return value

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have an issue where we are trying to automate a report for example in column b2 i may have the following string.

"(100 records executed) over 1000 ms of which 200 were within target and 800 not.)

I need to grab the number near ms (meaning Milliseconds) and populate that in A1 column however the string can be slighly different so i need the answer to a couple of situations

example 1 - i need 1000 to be returned
(100 records executed) over 1000 ms of which 200 were within target and 800 not.)

example 2 - this example i need 152ms to be returned, ignoring the first (ms)
(100 records executed) 100 in target under 200ms  however 700 over target with 152ms of which 200 were within target and 800 not.)

example 3 - ms sometimes appears before so i would need the numbers directly after
(100 records executed) 100 in target under ms200

I've tried something like this for another example where grabbing number after the word Call in VS but cant replicate for other scenarios mentioned in here

example code

```
Sub Formula_Property_1bracket()
   Dim Lastrow As Integer
Lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Range("G2:G" & Lastrow).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IFERROR(VALUE(MID(RC[1], (FIND(""("",RC[1])+1),FIND("" calls"",RC[1])-(FIND(""("",RC[1])+1))),""ERROR"")"
Range("G2").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("G2:G" & Lastrow), Type:=xlFillDefault
End Sub
```

Comment: You can improve your question by formatting code as code, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251361/17017616 . It would further benefit from adding better examples in the form of "given input" -> "expected output"

Comment: Did you try `VLookup()` with approximate match?

Answer (score 1):

Create a Custom UDF to get the value according to each example:

[image]

Formula in Cell B1 is: `=GET_MS(A1)`

Code for that UDF called `GET_MS` is:

```
Public Function GET_MS(ByVal rng As Range) As Double
Dim MyString As String

MyString = rng.Value

If InStr(1, MyString, "however", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
    GET_MS = CDbl(Split(Split(MyString, "over target with ")(1), "ms")(0))
ElseIf InStr(1, MyString, "were within", vbTextCompare) Then
    GET_MS = CDbl(Split(Split(MyString, " ms")(0), "over ")(1))
ElseIf InStr(1, MyString, "in target under", vbTextCompare) Then
    GET_MS = CDbl(Split(MyString, "ms")(1))
Else
    GET_MS = -1 'return zero if there is no match at all!!!
End If

End Function
```

Notice it returns -1 if there is no match for any of the examples provided. That means you need to update your UDF.

To extract specific parts of text I've used the command SPLIT. To check if specific text is present, I've used INSTR:

> [Split
> function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/split-function)
>
> [InStr
> function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/instr-function)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
Sub test()
    
    On Error GoTo myEnd
    'check if in string is "ms"
    'i tested only one specific cell where i changed your three posibilities of string
    'you have to chenge it to dynamically move through your data in rows or whereever you have it
    If InStr(ActiveSheet.Cells(3, "C").Value, "ms") > 1 Then
        On Error GoTo 0
        'split string with "ms"
        arr = Split(ActiveSheet.Cells(3, "C").Value, "ms")
        arr1 = Split(Trim(arr(0)), " ")
        arr2 = Split(Trim(arr(1)), " ")
        'case for two "ms"
        If UBound(arr) = 2 Then
            arr3 = Split(Trim(arr(2)), " ")
        End If
        
        'test the string before and after "ms" if they are numeric
        If UBound(arr) = 1 Then
            If IsNumeric(Trim(arr1(UBound(arr1)))) = True Then
                myValue = Trim(arr1(UBound(arr1)))
            ElseIf IsNumeric(Trim(arr2(0))) = True Then
                myValue = Trim(arr2(0))
            End If
            
        'test the string before and after "ms" if they are numeric - case for two "ms" in string
        ElseIf UBound(arr) = 2 Then
            If IsNumeric(Trim(arr2(UBound(arr2)))) = True Then
                myValue = Trim(arr2(UBound(arr2)))
            ElseIf IsNumeric(Trim(arr3(0))) = True Then
                myValue = Trim(arr3(0))
            End If
        End If
    End If
    
    ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1) = myValue
    myEnd:
    End Sub
```